# Catching nested errors in invoked methods Java

Tags: java, exception, invoke

First of all I am not really sure what exactly the reason for this behaviour is, so the title might be wrong.

I have one "MainClass" which creates a new Object of a "SubClass" by using the [`Method.invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) method (with a because there are several "SubClasses" all having the same method, if you a better way of solving this, I would appreciate it). As exceptions thrown by the `invoke()` method needs to be caught I have a `try {} catch () {}` around it. Now it seems like when one of the "SubClasses" throws an error and it is not directly in the code below a `try` block, it does not catch it but instead the "MainClass" catches it.

I don't know if this is the intended behaviour, but I would appreciate a way to prevent this from happening.

Example:

1. MainClass invokes method of SubClass
2. Method tries for example to do this `new Gson().fromJson("Test",ArrayList.class);` in a `try` block
3. MainClass catches the Exception

Comment: Provide a code example for a more exact answer, but any code wrapped in a `try-catch` block that throws a type of exception specified in the `catch` clause, will be handled in that same function call.

Comment: *because there are several "SubClasses" all having the same method, if you a better way of solving this, I would appreciate it*: err yes: declare it in the base class/interface, and override it in subclasses. That's what polymorphism is all about. Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: I am sorry if my questions are too easy for you, but I am just a beginner, so you don't have to be like that. And how would you do this with overriding it? By using `extends`?

Comment: I tried reproducing it but I can't with another class. Maybe I did something other wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apprently the problem was not Gson. What happeneds was that the

```
try {
    new Gson().fromJson(...);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logThatError();
}
```

Correctly catched an Exception thrown by Gson but the `logThatError()` caused an Exception as well.